# performance query in elasticsearch

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, filter, nest

I have 2 queries:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "idpays": 250
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "idpays": 250
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Theses 2 queries return the same results.
Which one has the best performance? The first one or the second one with `bool` and `must`?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Elasticsearch uses lucene under the hood all the queries are rewritten as simpler lucene queries before they are executed. If you use overly complicated queries to do a simple task, it will take Elasticsearch more time to rewrite the query into a simpler one.

add "profile": true at the root of your query to return a detailed analysis of the performance stats of the query and take a look at the rewrite time.
The larger the time the more complex the query is. A quick look tells me the second one should be slower but you should analyze the results yourself.